# How attach a sequence of numbers to a string using `paste0` in R?

Tags: r, plot, paste

I'm trying to a create `labels` for `dotchart()` below. Specifically, I'm trying to create `Yes_1` to `Yes_5` under **group 1** in `groups` below, and create `No_1` to `No_15` under **group 2** in `groups` below (***see picture below***).

**Here is the R code I have tried with no success:(problem is in `paste0()`)**

```
y = rnorm(20)
groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )
dotchart(y, groups = groups, labels = c(paste0("Yes_",1:5), paste0("No_", 1:15))[groups])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = rnorm(20)
groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )
dotchart(y, groups = groups, labels = c(paste0("Yes_",5:1), paste0("No_", 15:1)))
```

If we remove the `[groups]` index at line 3, and reverse the ranges, then we obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the `[group]` at the end. And reverse the order of the ranges if you want them like this.

```r
y = rnorm(20)
groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )
dotchart(y, groups = groups, labels = c(paste0("Yes_",5:1), paste0("No_", 15:1)))
```

[image]